# R: aggregate dataframe but different column

Tags: r, merge, aggregate

My data looks like this:

```
browsers.id browsers.label browsers.count browsers.id.1 browsers.label.1 browsers.count.1 
OS;FBSV        OS;FBSV            6        Chrome           Chrome                3 
Chrome         Chrome             86       Safari           Safari                47 
Chrome         Chrome             21       OS;FBSV          OS;FBSV               14
```

I want to aggregate or merge data to:

```
browsers.id count
Chrome       110
OS;FBSV      20
Safari       47
```

I try to use aggregate function,

```
aggregate(data[ ,3], list(data$browser.id), sum)
```

But it occurs error:

```
"arguments must have same length"
```

Could I fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We subset the 'id', and 'count' columns, convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(..`), reshape the 'wide' format to 'long' using `melt` (the data.table `melt` can take multiple `measure` columns), grouped by 'browsers.id', we get the `sum` of 'count'.

```
library(data.table) 
 melt(setDT(df1[c(1,3,4,6)]), measure=patterns('id', 'count'), 
   value.name=c('browsers.id','count'))[,list(count=sum(count)) ,
         by = browsers.id]
 #   browsers.id count
 #1:     OS;FBSV    20
 #2:      Chrome   110
 #3:      Safari    47
```

---

Or another option would be to `rbind` the 'id', 'count' columns

```
  rbindlist(list(df1[c(1,3)], df1[c(4,6)]))[,  
           list(count= sum(browsers.count)) ,browsers.id]
```

Comment: Thanks! Because I have more than six column, I try "setDT(df1)" and it works :)